Where to see owned Nintendo eShop games in browser
Is there a way to view which games I own in the Nintendo eShop using a browser?
I have already checked the purchase history, but that only goes back 2 years. I want to check from the browser because my new Switch isn't here yet.
Sadly the answer here didn't work for me.

This is probably cheating, but it's the only solution I found.
Reading the transaction history page on Nintendo Support site it's stated:

A receipt for each transaction in the Nintendo Switch eShop is emailed to the Nintendo Account that made the purchase. Please review your emails for a full history of your transactions.

So you can check your inbox (if you don't usually delete mails) and search for every mail from no-reply@accounts.nintendo.com having as subject "thank you for your purchase" or something like that.

This technically does fall within the OPs "using a browser" requirement

I should have thought of that considering I use this trick for plenty of other things...
